# How do I make sure on/off button stays on and off?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a new student to JS and I have created a HTML button to toggle on and off colours (the default colour "boxColor" is white)

```
var boxColor = 255;

document.querySelector('#toggleOn').addEventListener("click", function () {
    toggle(1);
});

document.querySelector('#toggleOff').addEventListener("click", function () {
    toggle(0);
});

var randomColors = setInterval(function () {
    boxColor = 'rgb(' + Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ',' + Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ',' + Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ')';
}, 500);

function toggle(state) {
    if (state == 0) {
        boxColor = 255;
    } else {
        clearInterval(randomColors);
    }
};
```

Now, I have the buttons set in HTML and when I opened the page, the colours are being refreshed every second (which is what I want). But when I clicked toggle off to turn it off, it continues to refresh new colours unless I click-and-hold the toggle off button.

Any ideas on how I could turn the colours from white to random on and off, and that it stays on (or off)?

Comment: Share your HTML also

Answer (score 0):

```js
var boxColor = 255;
var randomColors;
document.querySelector('#toggleOn').addEventListener("click", function () {
    toggle(1);
});

document.querySelector('#toggleOff').addEventListener("click", function () {
    toggle(0);
});


 randomColors = setInterval(function () {
    boxColor = 'rgb(' + Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ',' + Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ',' + Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ')';
console.log(boxColor);
}, 500);

function toggle(state) {
    if (state == 0) {
        boxColor = 255;
        console.log(boxColor);
        clearInterval(randomColors);
        randomColors = 0;
    } else {
        clearInterval(randomColors);
        randomColors = 0;
        console.log(boxColor);
    }
};
```

```html
<button id="toggleOn">On</button>
<button id="toggleOff">Off</button>
```

Comment: How about storing toggle value in localstorage? If toggleOn store value '1' in localstorage and similarly for toggleOff. Retrieve the stored value during page refresh.

Comment: localStorage.setItem('toggleData ',1); or localStorage.setItem('toggleData ',0); set this inside `click`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<button id="toggleOn">On</button>
<button id="toggleOff">Off</button>
<script>
var boxColor = 255;
var randomColors;
var storeddata=localStorage.getItem("state");
//CHECK STORED VALUE
if (storeddata == "0") {
boxColor = 255;
console.log(boxColor);
clearInterval(randomColors);
randomColors = 0;
}
if(storeddata == "1"){
clearInterval(randomColors);
randomColors = 0;
console.log(boxColor);
}

document.querySelector('#toggleOn').addEventListener("click", function () {
toggle(1);
localStorage.setItem("state", "1");
});

document.querySelector('#toggleOff').addEventListener("click", function () {
toggle(0);
localStorage.setItem("state", "0");
});


randomColors = setInterval(function () {
boxColor = 'rgb(' + Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ',' + Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ',' + Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ')';
console.log(boxColor);
}, 500);

function toggle(state) {
if (state == 0) {
boxColor = 255;
console.log(boxColor);
clearInterval(randomColors);
randomColors = 0;
} else {
clearInterval(randomColors);
randomColors = 0;
console.log(boxColor);
}
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```